# Converting GTA Vice City ADF audio files to MP3

Tags: c++, c++11, console, makefile

I wrote a tiny command line tool that converts [ADF audio files](http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php?title=GTA_ADF) from the
[*Grand Theft Auto - Vice City*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto%3A_Vice_City) game to MP3 files that can be played outside the game.

The ADF file format stores the game soundtracks and radio stations. These in turn
are just MP3 files that had every byte *XORed* with the decimal constant `34`.

My application is very simple, it only takes one or two file names
and processes every byte of the input file, producing a MP3 as output.

Usage example:

```
$ ./adf2mp3 flash.adf
```

Looks for the file "flash.adf" in the current directory and writes a
file named "flash.mp3" to the current directory as its output. You can
also provide an explicit output filename as the third parameter.

#### adf2mp3.cpp:

```
// Standard C++ includes:
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Standard C / POSIX includes:
#include <cerrno>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

namespace adf2mp3
{

using ubyte = unsigned char;
using ulong = unsigned long;

//
// The GTA Vice City ADF files are MP3 files that
// had each byte XORed with this magic constant.
// 34 is 22 in hexadecimal and 42 in octal...
//
// Not sure who figured this out, but I got this
// info from the Xentax File Format Wiki.
//
constexpr ubyte GtaMagic = 34;

//
// Process the input file in chunks of this size in bytes.
// The chunk buffer is allocated dynamically (it is a std::vector)
// so this can be a fairly large value.
//
constexpr ulong ChunkSize = 8192;

// ========================================================

struct FileStats
{
    ulong fileLength;   // File length in bytes.
    bool  isDirectory;  // True if the path provided pointed to a directory.
    bool  isNormalFile; // True is the path provided pointed to a file.
};

FileStats fileStatsForPath(const std::string & pathname)
{
    errno = 0; // Clear the errno global, just in case.
    struct stat statBuf;

    if (stat(pathname.c_str(), &statBuf) != 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Path '" + pathname + "': " + std::string(std::strerror(errno)));
    }

    FileStats fs;
    fs.fileLength = static_cast<ulong>(statBuf.st_size);

#if _WIN32
    fs.isDirectory  = (statBuf.st_mode & _S_IFDIR) ? true : false;
    fs.isNormalFile = (statBuf.st_mode & _S_IFREG) ? true : false;
#else // !_WIN32
    fs.isDirectory  = S_ISDIR(statBuf.st_mode) ? true : false;
    fs.isNormalFile = S_ISREG(statBuf.st_mode) ? true : false;
#endif // _WIN32

    return fs;
}

std::string removeExtension(const std::string & filename)
{
    const auto lastDot = filename.find_last_of('.');
    if (lastDot == std::string::npos)
    {
        return filename;
    }
    return filename.substr(0, lastDot);
}

void printHelpText(const char * programName)
{
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Usage:\n";
    std::cout << "$ " << programName << " <input_file> [output_file]\n";
    std::cout << "  Runs the tool normally. If the output filename is not provided\n" <<
        "  the input filename is used but the extension is replaced with '.mp3'.\n";

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Usage:\n";
    std::cout << "$ " << programName << " --help | -h\n";
    std::cout << "  Prints this help text.\n";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void handleCommandLine(int argc, const char * argv[],
                       std::string & inFileName, std::string & outFileName,
                       bool & printHelpOnly, bool & missingArgs)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        missingArgs = true;
        return;
    }

    if (std::strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0 || std::strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0)
    {
        printHelpOnly = true;
        return;
    }

    // input_file + output_file
    if (argc >= 3)
    {
        inFileName  = argv[1];
        outFileName = argv[2];
    }
    else // Just input_file
    {
        inFileName = argv[1];
        outFileName.clear();
    }

    printHelpOnly = false;
    missingArgs   = false;
}

void processChunk(std::vector<ubyte> & chunk, ulong numBytes)
{
    for (ulong b = 0; b < numBytes; ++b)
    {
        chunk[b] ^= GtaMagic;
    }
}

void processFiles(const std::string & inFileName, const std::string & outFileName)
{
    const FileStats fileStats = fileStatsForPath(inFileName);

    if (fileStats.fileLength == 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Input file is empty!");
    }

    if (fileStats.isDirectory)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Input file '" + inFileName + "' is a directory!");
    }

    std::ifstream inFile(inFileName,   std::ifstream::in  | std::ifstream::binary);
    std::ofstream outFile(outFileName, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);

    ulong bytesProcessed = 0;
    std::vector<ubyte> chunk(ChunkSize, 0);

    while (bytesProcessed != fileStats.fileLength)
    {
        const ulong bytesLeft = fileStats.fileLength - bytesProcessed;
        const ulong bytesThisIteration = std::min<ulong>(chunk.size(), bytesLeft);

        inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(chunk.data()), bytesThisIteration);
        processChunk(chunk, bytesThisIteration);
        outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(chunk.data()), bytesThisIteration);

        bytesProcessed += bytesThisIteration;
    }
}

void run(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    bool printHelpOnly, missingArgs;
    std::string inFileName, outFileName;
    handleCommandLine(argc, argv, inFileName, outFileName, printHelpOnly, missingArgs);

    if (printHelpOnly)
    {
        printHelpText(argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    if (missingArgs)
    {
        std::cout << "Not enough arguments!\n";
        printHelpText(argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Replace .adf extension of source file with .mp3 and use
    // it for the output if no explicit filename was provided.
    if (outFileName.empty())
    {
        outFileName = removeExtension(inFileName) + ".mp3";
    }

    processFiles(inFileName, outFileName);
}

} // namespace adf2mp3 {}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    try
    {
        adf2mp3::run(argc, argv);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

I also wrote a minimal makefile for it. Would appreciate comments on it:

```
COMPILER = c++
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -O3
FILES    = adf2mp3.cpp
OUTPUT   = adf2mp3

all:
    $(COMPILER) $(CPPFLAGS) $(FILES) -o $(OUTPUT)

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUT)
```

I should note that I'm aware about the convention of reading/writing from/to
stdin & stdout when no filename(s) are provided, but I don't think I'll add this
feature at the moment.

[Repository link](https://bitbucket.org/glampert/adf2mp3). I'm looking for second opinions mostly. Is there anything I can do to improve this? Nitpicking is also welcome.

Comment: NB: `CPPFLAGS` should be reserved for _pre-processor_ flags, e.g. `-I<path>` - use `CXXFLAGS` for _compiler_ phase flags.

Comment: There are built-in rules for converting c++ files to .o files, and those rules use pre-defined macro names such as `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS` (for C) and `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: FWIW, the only thing in the code that looks out-of-place to me is the use of `std::vector<ubyte>` when a `char[]` parameter to the `fstream` `read` and `write` functions would work perfectly well and without the casts.

Comment: @Alnitak, thanks, I rarely use "raw" makefiles, so my knowledge is limited. And to tell you the truth, originally I had that buffer as a stack declared array, but then I thought: someone is going to give me a hard time for placing such a big array on the stack. Then I changed it to a heap-allocated vector `:P`.

Comment: Technically, your `vector` is actual on the stack, but behind the scenes it'll use the heap for storage.  For code this simple I would just use `char *chunk = new char[chunkSize]` ....  `delete[] chunk`

Comment: @Alnitak, That would be worse than a vector, since you have to manually deallocate. But I guess I misunderstood your point. I think you meant the casts look ugly?

Comment: A `unique_ptr<char[]>` would be good, modern C++. But vector is preferable since most compilers provide debug bounds checking for `operator[]`. I would NOT use a raw pointer though.

Comment: IMHO, correctly written code doesn't need bounds checks ;-)

Comment: Hehe, @Alnitak I'm taking all the help I can get. My view of code is: with bugs until proven otherwise ;)

Comment: regarding the bounty, I'm honestly not sure what to suggest because IMHO the code is actually pretty good.  If I had one additional comment it would be to wrap up your own definition of the two `stat()` related macros for WIN32 outside of the `fileStatsForPath` function so that the code inside that function doesn't have the conditional compilation in it (or alternatively if you already have boost, use `<boost/filesystem>` instead.

Comment: @Alnitak, feel free to expand your answer. If nothing else pops up, I'll gladly award you the bounty. Thanks for the compliment, BTW `;)`

Comment: Also, in order to avoid reinventing the wheel, use one of the existing command-line parsers such as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865668/parse-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your program is overly complicated.** That's my first thought I've had while reading your code. Don't overly complicate your problem but [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

- You don't need to care whether you're trying to open a directory: you just can't open a directory as a file.
- Following, you don't need `FileStats`.

  - => You don't need `stat`.
- You should be throwing a `system_error` ( : public `runtime_error` ) which will provide a modern way to retrieve error messages (can be used in a cross-platform manner, too).
- You don't need a namespace.
- In `printHelpText` consider that each `cout` is a different call. You can chain them in just one thanks to string literal chaining (done by the preprocessor) and cascading calls:

  ```
  std::cout << "\n"
               "Usage:\n"
               "$ " << programName << " <input_file> [output_file]\n"
               "Runs the tool normally. If the output filename is not provided\n" 
               "the input filename is used but the extension is replaced with '.mp3'.\n"
               "\n";
      // ...
  ```
- In `processFiles` you're still complicating your life. A `vector` is "overkill": you just need an `unique_ptr`.
- To get the file size, you can:

  ```
   std::ifstream in(filename, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
   auto size = in.tellg();
   in.seekp(ios::begin);
  ```
- I would avoid `adf2mp3::run` and, in general, run/init functions in the global namespace: that's what `main` is supposed to do.

### Details

- If you want to be pedantic, `unsigned char` may be larger than 8 bits (incredibly uncommon nowadays): you'd better use `std::uint8_t`.
- I don't think a loop is needed as it should write it all in one time (unlike low-level I/O).
- Setting `errno` to zero isn't really necessary (as you stated) because you're supposed to check it only if a (C) function returns a value indicating a failure and sets it accordingly.
- I'm not sure if you can use `const char *argv[]` but the legal signatures of `main` are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c).

Comment: Hi @black, Thanks for your input. Your code formatting was broken, so I took the liberty of editing it. Please make sure I didn't change anything I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 2):

My only objection is the overuse of `std::vector()` when none of the features of the vector are actually being used.

I would suggest instead making the `processChunk` function work directly on a `char *`:

```
void processChunk(char *p, size_t n) {
    while (n--) {
        *p++ ^= GtaMagic;
    }
}
```

and then having declared your `std::vector` (which should use the `char` type expected by `ifstream::read`, not `ubyte`) you only need to deference its `data()` element once:

```
std::vector<char> chunk(chunkSize, 0);
char *data = chunk.data();
inFile.read(data, bytesThisIteration);
processChunk(data, bytesThisIteration);
outFile.write(data, bytesThisIteration);
```

Comment: Is the XOR instruction affected by the signedness of `char`? I'm not sure. But if not, then my `ubyte` could very well just be replaced by a plain `char`.

Comment: AFAIK, the `xor` will not be affected by the sign - it'll just work on the raw binary representation.   FWIW, the code above was replaced with a SSE 16-byte at a time loop using `clang -O3` but the version using `std::vector<char>` only works on one byte at a time.

Comment: Humm, that's disappointing about the vector. I should check the assembly output more often... Not that I care about performance that much in this case, but one would expect the vector code to be inlined, producing similar results...

Comment: @glampert well, it was at least inlined into a tight four instruction loop, but the optimiser appeared unable to take the same leap into SSE instructions that it was able to with the "C style" loop.

Comment: In fact, only `-O2` was required, and it also unrolled the loop to do 32 bytes per branch.  That's a smart optimiser :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `processFiles()` has several problems.

First, the name. It appears to process a single file, but the name suggests it processes multiple files. I'd change it to `processFile()`.

Second, error checking. You have to check if the `ifstream inFile` and `ofstream outFile` were constructed successfully, that is, whether the files named `inFileName` and `outfileName` were opened successfully. One way is to check the `.fail()` method; another way is to set the failbit in the exception mask of each object and then handle the exception elsewhere (but then you'd have to construct it first, set the failbit, and finally open it).

Third, I don't think there's any benefit in keeping track of how `bytesLeft` or `bytesProcessed`. Just ask for `ChunkSize` bytes each time, then assign `bytesThisTime = inFile.gcount();` for use by `processChunk()` and `outFile.write()`. Then the loop condition is to check for `eof()` or `fail()` (which is needed anyway since operations on a file can fail after the file is open too).

I also don't see any need for `FileStats fileStats`. The only thing you use it for is to get the file length, but that's of no benefit. You're not checking the files to determine if they're valid MP3s, so a 0-byte input file should process to a 0-byte output file, not an exception. Plus, checking for emptiness does not guarantee you'll be able to open the file successfully.

Comment: Interesting points, thanks! Error checking is truly lacking. About `processFiles`, the way I see it, it does handles 2 files, the input (ADF) and output (MP3).

Comment: So you're using both definitions of "processed" at the same time: the input to a process, and the output of a process. I've never seen that usage before, and certainly never with the active form of the verb.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know, I guess `processFile` (singular) would be good too, since it is one input file, the output file being the result of the processing. I'm starting to catch your drift.

Answer (score 0):

#### Comments on the Makefile:

I suggest adding the `-g` flag, which enables debugging mode.

Moreover, I don't see why use `c++` over `g++`. On the other hand I don't see why not. See: [g++ and c++ - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712756/g-and-c-compiler)

---

I usually create/compile the individual files **separately**, but in your case you seem to have only one file, thus no need for this option. To be precise, when I use this option, I then use clean to delete all object files. This has pros and cons, of course.

The drawback is that you have to compile every file again, but that is something that the computer does. The main advantage, IMHO, is that you don't put more files in the workspace, which might have already many files.

Comment: You mean you didn't test the code, right? It's OK. I was under the impression that `c++` was more portable then `g++`, but that might be wrong. `g++` on OSX is an alias to `Clang`, so it should be fine to use it. Yes, ideally I should add more rules to the makefile to compile each file separately, but since I have only a single source file, I didn't bother. Thanks for the comments. Welcome to code review, btw!

Comment: Yes I didn't. Yes I agree with the one file you mention. However, the debugging flag seems nice. You are welcome and thanks! :)

Comment: "Production" builds shouldn't have the `-g` flag, and the use of `c++` vs `g++` is architecture specific - there's zero useful content in this answer.