# Rust version of my C++ command-line tool

Tags: beginner, console, rust

First program I've written in Rust (besides the demos in the [tutorial site](http://rustbyexample.com/)).

I decided to start by [converting my C++ command line tool](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/75011/39810) to Rust. This is not necessarily a 1 to 1 conversion, but I've tried to maintain the overall structure the same:

```
// Currently (rustc 1.0.0-nightly), these modules are all unstable
// and would generate warnings without these suppressions.
#![feature(io)]
#![feature(path)]
#![feature(collections)]

use std::fs::File;
use std::fs::Metadata;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::prelude::*;

// ========================================================

// The GTA Vice City ADF files are MP3 files that
// had each byte XORed with this magic constant.
// 34 is 22 in hexadecimal and 42 in octal...
//
// Not sure who figured this out, but I got this
// info from the Xentax File Format Wiki.
//
static GTA_MAGIC : u8 = 34;

// Process the input file in chunks of this size in bytes.
// The chunk buffer is allocated dynamically (it is a Vec)
// so this can be a fairly large value.
//
static CHUNK_SIZE : usize = 8192;

// ========================================================

fn print_help_text(program_name : &String) {
    println!("");
    println!("Usage:");
    println!("$ {} <input_file> [output_file]", program_name);
    println!("  Runs the tool normally. If the output filename is not provided");
    println!("  the input filename is used but the extension is replaced with '.mp3'.");
    println!("");
    println!("Usage:");
    println!("$ {} --help | -h", program_name);
    println!("  Prints this help text.");
    println!("");
}

fn remove_extension(filename : &String) -> String {
    let path = Path::new(filename);
    return String::from_str(path.file_stem()
                .unwrap().to_str().unwrap());
}

fn open_file(filename : &String) -> (File, Metadata) {
    let path = Path::new(filename);

    // `open()` is read-only by default.
    let file_handle = match File::open(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("Couldn't open file {}: {}", path.display(), why.description()),
        Ok(file_handle) => file_handle,
    };

    let file_info = match file_handle.metadata() {
        Err(why) => panic!("Unable to get metadata for {}: {}", path.display(), why.description()),
        Ok(file_info) => file_info,
    };

    // Return a pair of file handle and its metadata:
    return (file_handle, file_info);
}

fn create_file(filename : &String) -> File {
    let path = Path::new(filename);

    // `create()` is write-only by default.
    return match File::create(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("Couldn't create file {}: {}", path.display(), why.description()),
        Ok(file_handle) => file_handle,
    };
}

fn process_files(input_filename : &String, output_filename : &String) {
    // Source file (ADF):
    let in_file_tuple = open_file(input_filename);
    let in_file_len   = in_file_tuple.1.len() as usize; // Index 1: Metadata
    let mut in_file   = in_file_tuple.0;                // Index 0: File

    // Destination file (MP3):
    let mut out_file = create_file(output_filename);

    // Chunk processing loop:
    let mut bytes_processed : usize = 0;
    while bytes_processed != in_file_len {
        let bytes_left = in_file_len - bytes_processed;
        let bytes_this_iteration = std::cmp::min(CHUNK_SIZE, bytes_left);

        let mut chunk = vec![0u8; bytes_this_iteration];

        match in_file.read(chunk.as_mut_slice()) {
            Err(why) => panic!("Failed to read input file! {}", why.description()),
            Ok(_) => {},
        };

        chunk = chunk.map_in_place(|byte| byte ^ GTA_MAGIC);

        match out_file.write(chunk.as_mut_slice()) {
            Err(why) => panic!("Failed to write output file! {}", why.description()),
            Ok(_) => {},
        };

        bytes_processed += bytes_this_iteration;
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Fetch command line:
    let cmd_args : Vec<String> =
            std::env::args()
                .map(|x| x.to_string())
                    .collect();

    // Too few command line args, exit:
    if cmd_args.len() < 2 {
        println!("Not enough arguments!");
        print_help_text(&cmd_args[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Print help and exit if "-h" or "--help" present in cmd line:
    if cmd_args.len() > 1 && (cmd_args[1] == "-h" || cmd_args[1] == "--help") {
        print_help_text(&cmd_args[0]);
        return;
    }

    //
    // Normal execution path:
    //
    let input_filename : String;
    let mut output_filename : String;

    if cmd_args.len() >= 3 {
        // input_filename + output_filename:
        input_filename  = cmd_args[1].clone();
        output_filename = cmd_args[2].clone();
    } else {
        // Just input_filename:
        input_filename  = cmd_args[1].clone();
        output_filename = String::new();
    }

    // Replace ".adf" extension of source filename with ".mp3" and use
    // it for the output if no explicit filename was provided.
    if output_filename.is_empty() {
        output_filename = remove_extension(&input_filename) + ".mp3";
    }

    process_files(&input_filename, &output_filename);
}
```

I'm looking for comments on style, design, nitpicking, anything to improve the code, really.

Specifically, the file processing loop seems to be somewhat inefficient and doing a lot of allocations/deallocations. I couldn't figure out how to read/write chunks of a file in a simpler way; `read()/write()` both infer the number of bytes to operate on from the input array, so I had to allocate a new one each iteration. Seems wasteful...

**Edit note:**

Initially I was not compiling the Rust code with proper optimizations enabled (see [@Shepmaster](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32521/shepmaster)'s comment below), which produced very poor timings when compared with the C++ code (rookie's mistake, no doubt `;)`). With `-O` added to the command line, it performed slightly faster than the C++ equivalent on my machine. Not bad at all!

Comment: The most important question for timing: *did you compile with optimizations*? `rustc -O foo.rs` or `cargo {build,run} --release`.

Comment: Ha, good point, @Shepmaster, just the compiler defaults, for both.

Comment: @Shepmaster, you sir wins the internet for today, faster then the C++ one when compiled with `-O`! I'll edit this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some feedback, in no interesting order:

```
// Current
static GTA_MAGIC : u8 = 34;
// Preferred 
const GTA_MAGIC: u8 = 34;
```

Two fixes here - Using `const` instead of `static`. `static` items exist in the compiled code, and can have their address taken. You don't need that here, so prefer `const`. Also, don't put spaces before the `:` when describing types.

```
// Current
fn print_help_text(program_name: &String) {
// Preferred
fn print_help_text(program_name: &str) {
```

Prefer to accept `&str` when you are just reading a string. This allows more things to be provided to the function, including static strings.

```
// Current
return (file_handle, file_info);
// Preferred
(file_handle, file_info)
```

Don't use explicit return statements at end of functions.

```
// Current
chunk = chunk.map_in_place(|byte| byte ^ GTA_MAGIC);
// Preferred
for byte in &mut chunk { *byte ^= GTA_MAGIC }
```

`map` (or `map_in_place`) isn't idiomatic when used just for side-effects. Just use a simple `for` loop.

```
match out_file.write(chunk.as_mut_slice()) {
    Ok(_) => {}, // OH NOES
};
```

`write` is not guaranteed to write all the bytes you asked for! Ignoring the result here means that you don't know how much was written, and may be **losing data**.

```
for byte in in_file.bytes() {
    let byte = byte.ok().unwrap();
    out_file.write(&[byte ^ GTA_MAGIC]).unwrap();
}
```

Instead of the whole buffering loop thing, try this simpler version. I punted on graceful error-handling. If you see performance decrease, I'd suggest wrapping `in_file` and `out_file` in `BufferedReader` / `BufferedWriter` instances.

```
let cmd_args: Vec<_> =
    std::env::args()
    .map(|x| x.to_string())
    .collect();
```

Method chains should be at the same level of indentation. You can also leave out `String` and let the compiler infer it for you.

```
// Current
let mut output_filename: String; 
// Preferred
let mut output_filename;
```

Don't write out type names when you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty detailed. Believe it or not, I used the map method because I couldn't figure out the proper syntax to write a for loop that mutates the array `:P`. Just one thing, I didn't get your last point, about the type names. `output_filename` is used.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I get it, you meant qualifying the type, e.g.: `: String`, OK!

Comment: Yup. I also added before / after to the examples to make them easier to parse.

Comment: On the `let cmd_args` line, styles differ substantially, though the questioner’s style is not at all common. For a case like this, it’s short enough that I would just write it all on a single line.